# Set class on thumbnail images in plugin list category post

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I am hoping that someone can help me - How can I set the Class on the Thumbnail images?

I have looked here: In the catList.php file

```
 $lcp_thumbnail = '<a href="' . get_permalink($single->ID).'">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($single->ID, $this->params['thumbnail_size']) . '</a>';
```

The default class on the thumbnail looks like this - `class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image"`

It would be great to set the class on the thumbnail image, via the shortcode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This feature was implemented on [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) version 0.21 :)

> **thumbnail_class** - Set a CSS class to the thumbnail and style it.